# NotNull attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm looking at asp.net vnext [engineering guideline](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Engineering-guidelines) and have noticed that they recommend to use `NotNull` attribute instead of explicit checking of input argument for null and throwing `ArgumentNullException`. The thing that confused me is that base on this guideline it is just enough to declare this attribute and the checking code will be generated at compile time into the method body. I've tried to do this in my test project however the magic didn't happen i.e. it threw the exception `System.NullReferenceException` instead of `System.ArgumentNullException`. How this is supposed to work? Are they going to use some AOP library to inject the checking code at compile time?

Comment: @usr In ASP.NET 5/DNX, you can add precompilation steps that modify the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806369/using-notnull-for-a-methods-parameters/37030122 talks about how you can use build weavers to achieve this

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `NotNullAttribute` is gone. It was [replaced with conditionally throwing `ArgumentNullException`](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/commit/8f239785c01e76dd58a36c9975f3b4ac0781ad0b) and subsequently [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/commit/610d6115070f055763d8e2728e7428a8b2702519) by the ASP.NET team. As of Jan 12, 2016 there's no plan to bring it back. (At that time, I was working on the ASP.NET team.)

---

<strike>The attribute will be replaced through a pre-compilation step, using Roslyn, by code that does the actual check.</strike>

However, the feature is not yet ready as of Jun 17, 2015. It will come in a later version. So far, it is just [an empty internal attribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/7ba8a4d008a309772a82571d29b2d7e0733f7195/src/Microsoft.Framework.NotNullAttribute.Internal/NotNullAttribute.cs) that [should be implemented in each project again](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/333):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: This attribute is for static analysis only. As of now, this will not be a compile time feature. [Not Null - Engineering Guidelines](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Engineering-guidelines#argument-null-checking)

Comment: Any comment, why it is removed? It's very useful, it even exist in R# annotations library.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Maybe you use Code Contracts instead.

Comment: Code contracts is also basically dead. Currently there is no good support for non nullable types imo.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I find it confusing that when reading the Engineering guidlines for the ASP Core project on github, they are still stipulating that you must use this attribute. So if we are to try and follow conventions that the Microsoft team themselves are using (https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Engineering-guidelines) to try and make our own projects follow the framework conventions as closely as possible, then surely this must still exist somewhere???

Comment: There is some talk of it being included in C#8.  https://ilovecsharp.com/2017/08/23/csharp-8-feature-review/

Comment: Looking at EF Core 2.0 by Microsoft, it's being used in source code (e.g. line 53) 

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.0/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs

Comment: @MEMark That's their own attribute: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/a3f0a78c41fe209924f8fb39fc77c421236f1bbe/src/Shared/CodeAnnotations.cs#L8

Comment: Is this not viable? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Comment: This is present in .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Is this still relevant today? It appears that [NotNull] has made a comeback.