# C# null value for a List even if it was initialized as empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that submits a ViewModel similar to this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<MyItem> MyList { get; set; } = new List<MyItem>();
}
```

The problem is that in some cases this List could be null, but I want to prevent this. I want this list to *never* be null.

I thought that initializing it would be enough, but I was wrong. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: could you provide the code of your view where you have performed binding of model with the HTML controls? Most probably, the issue would be at view level in this case

Comment: The view is fine, believe me, but that's not the point. The point is: even if the View was wrong returning a null value, I want that null value to be converted into an empty list instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `NotNull` attribute, it was just a skeleton and has no implementation. The MVC team was planning to do something with it but then they threw it away and its gone. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896853/notnull-attribute) answer for more.

Make sure your controller is passing a non-null list to all the views. The best way to do this is to create another model for your view and in the constructor of that model always `new` up the list and pass that model to your views.

Comment: NotNull is from Resharper annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom `ModelBinder`, inherit from the `DefaultModelBinder` and get the result from the base class, check the results and if it is NULL then initialize it to a new empty list.
Ex:

```
public class NotNullListBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {

        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(MyViewModel))
            {
                var result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
                if(result != null && result.MyList == null)
                 {
                    result.MyList = new new List<MyItem>();
                    return result;
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            }
        }

    }
```

And in your Global.asax.cs: you have to register this model binder and link it to your view model

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyViewModel), new NotNullListBinder ());
```